# C# WPF DataGrid Change cells color by value

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, highlight

I am new to WPF and trying to highlight Datagrid cells by their value.
I have loaded a list of items to the DataGrid, and I want to mark all the wrong input values (represented as value "0"):

[image]

Comment: Set validation rules for your DataGrid cells [How to: Implement Validation with the DataGrid Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee622975%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a simple sample to just guide you how it can be done

Xaml code

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" IsEnabled="True" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="275" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" Width="25"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Weight" Binding="{Binding Weight}" Width="25"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity}" Width="25"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Length" Width="25">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Length, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
                        <TextBox.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Length}" Value="0">
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBox.Style>
                    </TextBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Height" Binding="{Binding Height}" Width="25"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Width" Binding="{Binding Width}" Width="25"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="X" Binding="{Binding X}" Width="25"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Y" Binding="{Binding Y}" Width="25"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Z" Binding="{Binding Z}" Width="25"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Source { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Source = new ObservableCollection<Model>
        {
            new Model {ID=1,Weight=3,Quantity=5,Length=11,Height=12,Width=0,X=1,Y=-1,Z=-1 },
            new Model {ID=2,Weight=21,Quantity=23,Length=0,Height=23,Width=11,X=-1,Y=-1,Z=-1 }
        };
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = Source;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Just add the `UpdateSourceTrigger` in the `TextBox` within the `DataTemplate`

Comment: sorry, one follow-up question, how can I unmark the cell once the user edit the cell to a valid value? (greater than zero)

Comment: Sandesh, sorry to disturb you again but I have a little problem with that approach.
I have a DataGrid which all columns are DataGridTemplateColumn with this trigger. The only way that it works and updates the item, and the cell color is if i have an additional TextColumn and edit it too. Do you know a way around it?

Comment: There's no code, just needed to add regular column in addition to the DataGridTemplateColunn and edit it too.. I temporarily made it checkbox column so the user check the rows he's updating until I'll find a better solution.. When I remove this column and remain only with the templates columns it won't work..

Comment: The `DataTemplate` of each `DataGridTemplateColumn` is a `TextBox`?If no then can you please provide the xaml part of your DataGrid so that I can get a clear picture of what is going wrong

Comment: each column is defined as you given me, I can't add the xml here because its too long, but I did exactly like you showed in your answer, copy paste.

Comment: Currently there is no way to Reuse DataTrigger as each cell might have a different condition to trigger the style. I will try to think if I have some workarounds to see if a common style definition can take care of the styles if the triggers.