# Change cell color depending on value

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid with my total production divided into days and I have a goal to meet per week.

I need that if on Monday the goal was not met, the cell will be painted yellow and the same will happen until it is met and painted green. My goal is enter it manually in a textbox.

I get the value of the datatrigger from my query to my database, if it is 1 it is because it is in the current week, 0 if it is not.

It is currently green because it indicates what week we are currently in, how could I do what I want? Annex my code with which paints the week in which we are and the production made per day, and it should be clarified that
I am new working with wpf.
I hope you can help me, thanks.

```
            <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding semana}" Header="Semana">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding true}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding true}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>

            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Lunes}" Header="Lunes">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding true}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="green"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding true}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Lunes}" Value="">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Lunes}" Value="">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Martes}" Header="Martes">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding true}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="green"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding true}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Martes}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Miercoles}" Header="Miércoles">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding true}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="green"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding true}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Miercoles}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Jueves}" Header="Jueves">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding true}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="green"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Jueves}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding true}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Viernes}" Header="Viernes">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding true}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="green"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding true}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Viernes}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Sabado}" Header="Sábado">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding true}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="green"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding true}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Sabado}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Total}" Header="total">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding true}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="green"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding true}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding total}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665722/c-sharp-wpf-datagrid-change-cells-color-by-value

Comment: How do I compare the value of my cell with my textbox?

Comment: You have a similar trigger for all your DataGridCell, Instead you can have one trigger for the DataGridRow. You have multiple triggers for each DataGridCell, i hope you know that even if one DataTrigger condition is met it will implement the setter